# is there away to output selected columns names from SelectFromModel method?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

i performed feature selection using ExtraTreesClassifier and SelectFromModel in data set that loaded as DataFrame, however i want to save these selected feature as DataFrame to csv file while maintaining columns name as well. **note that output is numpy array** return important features whole columns not columns header

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv('los_10_one_encoder.csv')
y = df['LOS'] # target 
X= df.drop('LOS',axis=1) # drop LOS column 
clf = ExtraTreesClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X, y)
print clf.feature_importances_

model = SelectFromModel(clf, prefit=True)
X_new = model.transform(X)
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
model = SelectFromModel(clf, prefit=True)
feature_idx = model.get_support()
feature_name = df.columns[feature_idx]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the method `DataFrame.to_csv()` to save your dataframe as a `csv` file.

Do the following :

```
X_new.to_csv("your/path", sep=';')
```

[Here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) is a link to the documentation of the method.

Comment: i did that but X_new is numpy array

Comment: cast it then to a Dataframe. `X_new = pd.DataFrame(X_new)`

Comment: i am aware of this but i want to have columns names as well i.e if gender column has been chosen as important feature than i want to gender column header to print as well so i know which column is which