# How to filter the index by n letters and sum them together

Tags: python, pandas

This is a continuation of this question.

[is there away to output selected columns names from SelectFromModel method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41088576/is-there-away-to-output-selected-columns-names-from-selectfrommodel-method)

The output of this **feature_name = df.columns[feature_idx]** gives me many index names.

my question is, how can I only display the first 3 letters and show the total of each.

#### For example

My index output from the above is

```
Index(['banana good', 'banana bad', 'apple good', 'apple bad'])
```

I want it to display

```
ban - 2
app - 2
```

Comment: can you please make the question self-contained? Is the first part of the question even needed?

Comment: That we do not have to read the other question you linked to understand this one. Also what do you mean by the *"sum of the first 3 letters"*? How do you sum letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUIC, use

```
In [199]: idx = pd.Index(['banana good', 'banana bad', 'apple good', 'apple bad'])

In [200]: idx.str[:3].to_series().value_counts()
Out[200]:
app    2
ban    2
dtype: int64
```